# How to get Windows boot again

Tags: boot, partition, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I formatted the drive that contained Ubuntu Budgie, from MS-windows. Then I opened `cmd` with administrator privileges and head to diskpart and removed the Ubuntu directory from there, but maybe accidentally I also removed the boot directory and also tried to remove the Microsoft directory which gave an error or Denied. But I guess the boot directory was affected.

After a reboot I was unable to boot to MS-windows. When I am starting my computer my motherboard is doing some kind of scan and entering the bios. If I am heading to boot from disk, it is entering Grub rescue mode.

Then I installed Garuda Linux successfully from a flash drive, which I thought should overwrite the Grub, but maybe it didn't. Again after reboot when I am starting the computer, Grub rescue mode is appearing.

Then I connected a Windows iso flash drive and head over repair mode, opened up cmd and run the command `Bootrec.exe /FixMbr`

Which also didn't gave any single change to the result Then also tried `Bootrec.exe /FixBoot`

Again no improvement on result. Windows automatic repair systems are also failed. The only thing I am able to do is seeing the entire disk from a Garuda Linux flash drive.

Can anyone help?

```
#boot
#dual-boot
#partitioning
#grub2
#uefi
```

Comment: This question as it stands is off topic, it is about MS-Windows: I broke it using MS-Windows, and want to get MS-Windows working. However If you can't fix it with MS-Windows. You may be able to get grub to boot your MS-Windows. If you were to edit to ask how to do that, then it will be on topic.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install of Windows? UEFI or BIOS install of Linux? If UEFI, you should be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI menu. To fix Windows in UEFI mode you have to boot a Windows repair flash drive in UEFI mode. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair